# Jquery if statement inside a dynamic table creation

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have an "if" statement inside the code below to detect if the data is 1 or 0, if it's "1" change the colour of the table cell background?

My code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var data;
    $.get("get_timeline.php", function(data) {

        response = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                $('<td>').text(item.deviceid),
                $('<td>').text(item.mediatype),
                $('<td>').text(item.campainname),
                $('<td>').text(item.medianame),
                $('<td>').text(item.start_date),
                $('<td>').text(item.end_date),
                $('<td>').text(item.uploadflag)).appendTo('#records_table');
        });

    });
});
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Yes, but you would need to build the ```<tr ... >``` string separately, before you ```.append(...)``` it.

Comment: Modifying the DOM on each iteration triggers a reflow for every modification - and a [reflow can be quite expensive](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow). You're better of constructing all the rows at once and only append them in one go after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using `.toggleClass` and instead of using `if` you can use the conditional operator `?:`, to keep your chain, eg:

```
var $tr = $('<tr>').addClass(data === 1 ? "active" : "").append(
```

(or, on a single cell directly (note to self, read the question closer...))

```
$('<td>').addClass(item.active === 1 ? "active" : "").text(item.deviceid)
```

depends on whether you need a single cell or a the whole row (all cells) - you wouldn't want to add the above to every cell, use css instead eg `tr.active>td { background-color: yellow; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.toggleClass( className, state)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-state) to add a custom class to `TD` based on condition.

```
$('<td>').text(item.deviceid).toggleClass('your-class-which-set-background', item.deviceid === 1)
```

```js
var response = [{
    deviceid: 1
  },
  {
    deviceid: 2
  }
]
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
  var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
    $('<td>').text(item.deviceid).toggleClass('your-class-which-set-background', item.deviceid === 1)
  ).appendTo('#records_table');
});
```

```css
.your-class-which-set-background {
  background-color: #CCC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="records_table">
</table>
```